# C# Automatic Grow and shrink of control with form size

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, forms

I am building a programm right now but need a little help with C#. I want the programm to grow the controls with the form and shrink with the form but stay in the right relation with the form.

Comment: Try changing Anchor property of a control.

Comment: Try using MinHeight and MinWidth instead of Height and Width (in view).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
<DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
       <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="10,10,30,30">My control</Button>
</DockPanel>
```